# How to merge multiple text in multiple folders with consecutive numbering using batch script?

Tags: python, text, merge, batch-processing

I have 400 folders (named '1' to '400') containing multiple text files that I'd like to merge into one per folder and number after its folder's name (or at least provide with consecutive numbering in the file names).

I know how to merge files in the terminal using the cat command, but can only do this by hand for each single folder. I guess a batch script should make this a lot easier, but I'm new to batch scripting. Can anybody help me out?

I'm working on a Mac and have Python 2.7.9 installed.

Comment: Anything about Python can do?

Comment: [tag:batch-file] is **Windows**-related; Probably you meant [tag:batch-processing]; I edited the tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with bash like this:

```
for i in {1..400}
do
    cat $i/* > $i/$i
done
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I guessed it wouldn't be so complicated. How, though, can I give my merged file the same name as the folder it is in (1..400) instead of 'bigfile'?

Comment: @pimhuijnen i edit my answer, if my answer helped you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again!